# How to generate parse tree from antlr with command

Tags: parsing, antlr4

My file name is:
*Hello.g4*

Grammar is:

```
grammar Hello;
r  : 'hello' ID ;         
ID : [a-z]+ ;             
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

Antlr is used for the parse tree, but I don't know what the command to actually generate the parse tree is.

Comment: Are you talking about the invokation of the parser in the code or about a graphical representation of your parse tree?

Comment: Did my answer below not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I do.  First, compile the grammar using a batch file.  Your classpath variable may be different based on where your `jar` file is located.  This is for Windows:

```
SET CLASSPATH=.;D:\jarfiles\antlr-4.7-complete.jar;
java org.antlr.v4.Tool %*
```

Next you have to compile the resulting files:

```
javac Hello*.java
```

Finally, run the TestRig tool.  Again, I use a batch file.

```
java org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig %*
```

When you run TestRig, you supply the grammar name, the starting rule `r` in this case, and either type in the input or supply an input file.  the `-tokens` command-line option will show how your input is lexed; the `-gui` option will produce a graphical parse tree.